# Retrieve text from array

Tags: ios, nsarray

I am working on an app where I send a query to a webpage and get the information and save it into my array. Now, all this works except for then I come to take the value from my array and display it in my text view. using this code

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

 self.tvSoilN.text  = [[_soilNotes objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"crop"];
}
```

However, I get the error of the array being empty.
Now that makes sense because using a breakpoint I can see that the code above actually runs before the code be in my model.m file which I use to write the data in the array

I cant post images but when I use a break point on the if(self.delegate) line It shows me
_locations (and when i drill down i see)
_crop_soil(this is the field in my database)=@"Blah blah blah")
which makes me realize that  my data is indeed being retreived from online. But i am just having difficulty in displaying it from my array or anywhere.
Would like some help in especially where to call my array as I also think i am doing it wrong.Thanks you

**IN Implementation file**

```
-(void)itemsDownloaded:(NSArray *)items
{
    // This delegate method will get called when the items are finished downloading

    // Set the downloaded items to the array
    _soilN = items;



    NSLog(@"soil%@",_soilNotes);
    self.tvSoilN.text=[[_soil objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"crop"];
}
```

Comment: I can't see how you add items to _locations?

Comment: @pbasdf my bad, clipped it. added It to orginal question

Comment: In connectionDidFinishLoading you need to cause your view to redisplay.

Comment: @HotLicks didFinishLoading is not a part of my .M file. It is a model file and I send the data I get back to my M file thru the delegate

Comment: So, what is this then: `[self.delegate itemsDownloaded:_locations];` ???

Comment: @HotLicks self.delegate is the .m file. itemsDownloaded(I added the code in orginal question) is a method called and I pass in _locations to it.

Comment: So, tell your view to redisplay.

Comment: @HotLicks I am not exactly sure how to accomplish this. I cant even NSLog it

Comment: You can't add code to your itemsDownloaded method??

Comment: @HotLicks yes I can, but none that displays the values in my array

Comment: That's because you haven't added code to update your display yet.

Comment: self.tvSoilNotes.text  = [[_soilNotes objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"crop_soil"];
 Isnt this what I am attempting with this code?

Comment: Can you confirm: does itemsDownloaded get executed (if not, check self.delegate is set)?  If yes, does the NSLog show _soilNotes is populated?  Also, _locations is NSMutableArray, while itemsDownloaded takes an NSArray argument.  What class is soilNotes?  Are you effectively assigning an NSMutableArray to an NSArray?

Comment: @pbasdf sorry, I have been away. does itemsDownloaded gets executed after view did appear, so I cant even call a reload on the textbox to see if it will get data

Comment: Comment out the self.tvSoilnotes.... line in viewDidAppear and check what shows up in your NSLog in itemsDownloaded:

Comment: @pbasdf Actually it does show up in my NSLog, ive tested it already. Getting it to show in my textbox is whats keeping me

Comment: @pbasdf but the first viewdidload runs before the data is downloaded

Comment: Try using viewWillAppear rather than viewDidAppear.  And put the `self.tvSoilN.text...` line inside an if clause: `if (![_soilNotes count]) {...}`

Comment: @pbasdf I tried adding code to populate the textbox IN the itemsDownloaded method however, that seems to be failing cause I don't hve a dictionary I beieve

Comment: So if you `NSLog(@"Array has %i items",[_soil count];` what do value do you get?

Comment: Also, try `valueForKey` not `objectForKey`.

Comment: awww that solved it. it was valueForKey not objectForKey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `valueForKey` not `objectForKey`.  Got there in the end!